# Shall I use the conjunction, and in money amount?

Tags: conjunctions, numbers

I am filling in this textual amount on a cheque:
($32100)

I have learnt how to write numbers in words in school, for example,
101, it is one hundred and one
1010, it is one thounsand and one hundred

So, for this big number, 32100,
I think it should be

> thirty two thousand and one hundred

But Google told me that I should write this instead:

> thirty-two thousand one hundred

Is it wrong to use And?

Comment: Either is fine.  Some people write the "and", and some people don't.  Personally, I avoid writing checks if possible.

Comment: 1010 is "one thousand **and** ten" or "one thousand ten" not "one thousand and one hundred" which is 1100.

Comment: The and only goes between the hundreds and the tens. What google found was right in this case. If the amount had been: 32,101, you'd end up with two ***ands*** and that would be a mistake: thirty two thousand one hundred ***and*** one. NOT: thirty two thousand AND one hundred and one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both

> thirty two thousand and one hundred
>   thirty-two thousand one hundred

are correct.

However, due to the limited amount of space to write on a check, most people try to keep it as short as possible.